# Why does my skill behave differently when I move the helper functions to a different module?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to re-create the Alexa Quiz skill that's mentioned on [their public repository](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-quiz-game).  So far, the skill works correctly when the `index.js` file is exactly same as the one in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-quiz-game/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js). I'm trying to move the constants in a separate data file and the helper functions in another file. When I move the constants in the separate file, the code works correctly. However, when I move the helper functions into a different file the code starts behaving differently.

I moved the [constants](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-quiz-game/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js#L293-L364) to a different file called `data.js` and exported the variables in that file using

```
module.exports = {
  skillBuilder,
  imagePath,
  backgroundImagePath,
  correctAnswer,
  wrongAnswer,
  data,
  states,
  welcome,
  startQuiz,
  exitSkill,
  reprompt,
  help,
  useCardsFlag
};
```

In `index.js`, I imported the variables using `const Constants = require('data');`

I tested the code after doing this and it works correctly (as it should).

Now, I moved the [helper functions](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-quiz-game/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js#L365-L573) into a different file called `functions.js` and exported all the functions using

```
module.exports = {
  getBadAnswer,
  getCurrentScore,
  getFinalScore,
  getCardTitle,
  getSmallImage,
  getLargeImage,
  getImage,
  getBackgroundImage,
  getSpeechDescription,
  formatCasing,
  getQuestion,
  getQuestionWithoutOrdinal,
  getAnswer,
  getRandom,
  askQuestion,
  compareSlots,
  getItem,
  getSpeechCon,
  getTextDescription
};
```

and imported the functions using `const Helpers = require('functions');`.

Because the functions also refer the constants, I also imported the constants in  the `functions.js` using `const Constants = require('data');`

I expected the skill to work correctly. However, when I start the quiz using the skill, Alexa just utters the [Help message](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-quiz-game/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js#L362).

Here is are my code files:

1. [index.js](https://pastebin.com/nNd0YYGF)
2. [functions.js](https://pastebin.com/DvmHJnNS)
3. [data.js](https://pastebin.com/gSESqvkx)

I think what is happening is the variable states are not persisted between modules but I might be wrong. I have 2 questions:

1. Can anyone tell if my understanding of why this is happening is
   correct?
2. How to prevent this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a link to your source changes since the base code is already open source?

Comment: @icirellik - Done. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The link to your data.js code shows the same code as your functions.js.

Comment: @Dylan Changed link

Comment: You may have resolved this by now, but in your functions.js, you have module.export which should be module.exports. Could be the issue?

Comment: This was exactly the problem! Can you please respond this as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!